# Not able to retrieve data from controller

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-mvc-3

My controller code is like I am returning data as

```
public ActionResult StudentDashboard(int? page)
{    
    ViewBag.StudentRequest = GetData.Tables[0].AsEnumerable().Select(t => new
                                {
                                    StudentRequestId = t.Field<int>("StudentRequestId"),
                                    ClassName = t.Field<string>("ClassName"),
                                    CreatedOn = t.Field<DateTime>("CreatedOn"),
                                    Location = t.Field<string>("Location"),
                                    PaymentMethod = t.Field<string>("PaymentMethod"),
                                }).ToList().ToPagedList(page ?? 1,1);

    return View(db.StudentRequests.Where(x => x.RegistrationId ==  registrationid).ToList().ToPagedList(page ?? 1, 3));
}
```

Also how can I add inner join as class table in this code?

```
db.StudentRequests.Where(x => x.RegistrationId ==  registrationid)
                  .ToList()
                  .ToPagedList(page ?? 1, 3)
```

and on view side I have written code as

```
@using PagedList;
@using PagedList.Mvc;
@model IPagedList<Student_Tutor.Models.StudentRequest>

   @if (ViewBag.StudentRequest != null)
    { 
      var StudentRequestId = (int)Model.First().StudentRequestId;// Here I am able to get the StudentRequestId 
      var StudentRequestTimecount = StudentRequestTime.Where(d => d.StudentRequestId == StudentRequestId).ToList();
      var TutorStudentRequestcount = TutorStudentRequest.Where(d => d.StudentRequestId == StudentRequestId).ToList();
      @Html.LabelFor(model => model.First().StudentRequestId)// here only text is displaying as StudentRequestId
      @Html.DisplayNameFor(Model => Model.First().CreatedOn)//here only text is diplaying as created on
}
```

How can I get `StudentRequestId` record instead of only text at

```
@Html.LabelFor(model => model.First().StudentRequestId)
```

Through this code I am not able to get the Id number of `StudentRequestId` instead  of number the view side is showing only text.

Please see this screenshot:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `LabelFor` helper method render a label element with the name of the property or the DisplayName property if it was used to decorate the property.

If you want to print the value of the property, you may use `DisplayFor` helper method.

```
@Html.DisplayFor(model => model.First().StudentRequestId)
```

Comment: I had also tried using display for but still it was showing me the same text

Comment: I had tried for created on too but it is showing text only

Comment: If the `StudentRequestId` has a valid value, The `DisplayFor` helper will render that.

Comment: I just tried your code with `DisplayFor` in the view and it did print the value of it.

Comment: In my question I had also written with comments that on this line var StudentRequestId = (int)Model.First().StudentRequestId;// Here I am able to get the StudentRequestId .....I am able to get the value so what might be wrong that it is not displaying that value in DisplayFor

Comment: Have tried `DisplayNameFor` or  `DisplayFor` ? In your question you are using `DisplayNameFor`. You should use `DisplayFor`

Comment: that working, Can u help for second query too, that I had written in question only for inner join

Comment: Did you take a look at [Perform inner joins](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/linq/perform-inner-joins)

Comment: hey I have multiple row data in db. then why it is showing retriving only single data on view side?

Comment: Because your code is using the `First()` method which takes the first item from the collection. Use a `foreach` loop and render data inside that.

Comment: u mean foreach(var r in model.row){  }.....Sorry I am new in MVC so I really need help

Comment: as u suggested I had tried    var query = from sr in db.StudentRequests
                                                join c in db.Classes
                                                on sr.ClassId equals c.ClassId
                                                select new { sr.StudentRequestId,sr.ClassId };
                    return View(query.ToList().ToPagedList(page ?? 1, 2)); but it giving error as invalid operation

Comment: I suggest you post that as a new question with the specific code you tried for the JOIN and the error message you are getting.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47142158/how-should-i-pass-my-query-from-controller-using-topagedlist

Comment: can you look for https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47154713/how-to-implement-paging-in-mvc-with-sql-query this link too?