# How should I pass my query from controller using ToPagedList

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-mvc-3

Actually i want to integrate paging in my view page and for that I am retrieving data from below code and I am passing this code from controller to view but any how I am facing issue as

```
 var model = (from sr in db.StudentRequests
                join c in db.Classes
                on sr.ClassId equals c.ClassId
                select new { sr.StudentRequestId,c.ClassName,sr.CreatedOn,sr.Location,sr.PaymentMethod }).ToList().ToPagedList(page ?? 1, 1);           
  return View(model);
```

and I am getting issue as

```
Type : InvalidOperationException
Message : The model item passed into the dictionary is of type 'PagedList.PagedList`1[<>f__AnonymousType3`5[System.Int32,System.String,System.Nullable`1[System.DateTime],System.String,System.String]]', but this dictionary requires a model item of type 'PagedList.IPagedList`1[Student_Tutor.Models.StudentRequest]'.
Source : System.Web.Mvc
```

My view side is as

```
@using PagedList;
@using PagedList.Mvc;
@model IPagedList<Student_Tutor.Models.StudentRequest>
    @if (ViewBag.StudentRequest != null)
        { 
          var StudentRequestId = (int)Model.First().StudentRequestId;// Here I am able to get the StudentRequestId 
          var StudentRequestTimecount = StudentRequestTime.Where(d => d.StudentRequestId == StudentRequestId).ToList();
          var TutorStudentRequestcount = TutorStudentRequest.Where(d => d.StudentRequestId == StudentRequestId).ToList();
          @Html.Displayfor(model => model.First().StudentRequestId)// here only text is displaying as StudentRequestId
          @Html.Displayfor(Model => Model.First().CreatedOn)//here only text is diplaying as created on
    }
```

**please expalin why I am getting this error?**

**Update 1**

```
                var model = (from sr in db.StudentRequests
                              join c in db.Classes
                              on sr.ClassId equals c.ClassId
                              select new Studentvm{ StudentRequestId  = sr.StudentRequestId,ClassName= c.ClassName,
                              CreatedOn =Convert.ToDateTime(sr.CreatedOn),Location= sr.Location,PaymentMethod= sr.PaymentMethod })
                              .ToList().ToPagedList(page ?? 1, 1);

                return View(model);
```

but I am getting error as

```
An exception of type 'System.NotSupportedException' occurred in Student_Tutor.dll but was not handled in user code

Additional information: LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'System.DateTime ToDateTime(System.Object)' method, and this method cannot be translated into a store expression.
```

Comment: Because you are not following what i wrote in the answer. It should be like `select new StudentVm { StudentRequestId  = sr.StudentRequestId,`. Read the answer thouroughly

Comment: Had changed and is not showing the error but do i need to made changes on view?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This part of your LINQ code

```
select new { sr.StudentRequestId,c.ClassName,sr.CreatedOn,sr.Location,sr.PaymentMethod }
```

That is creating an annonymous object for each item in the result collection you get from your LINQ query and you are creating a `PagedList` from that. But your view is strongly typed to `PagedList<StudentRequest>`

The ideal solution is to create a viewmodel to represent the data needed for this view and use that in the projection part of your LINQ query

```
public class StudentVm
{
  public int StudentRequestId { set;get;}
  public string ClassName { set;get;}
  public DateTime CreatedOn { set;get;}
  public string Location { set;get;}
}
```

Now use this view model for your projection

```
  select new StudentVm { StudentRequestId  = sr.StudentRequestId,
                         ClassName= c.ClassName,
                         Location = sr.Location,
                         CreatedOn = sr.CreatedOn }
```

And make sure your view is not strongly typed to `PagedList<StudentVm>`

```
@using PagedList;
@model PagedList<YourNamespace.StudentVm>

<table>
    @foreach (var item in Model)
    {
        <tr>
            <td>@Html.DisplayFor(a=> item.ClassName)</td>
            <td>@Html.DisplayFor(a=> item.Location)</td>
            <td>@Html.DisplayFor(a=> item.StudentRequestId)</td>
            <td>@Html.DisplayFor(a=> item.CreatedOn)</td>
        </tr>
    }
</table>
```

Also, from your question, you are not really using the PagedList. To pass just a list of items, you do not need to convert that to `PagedList<T>` . You can simply send a `List<StudentVm>` from action method and change your view to be strongly typed to do that. Use `PagedList` if you are really using it (for paging)

Comment: Do I also need to change the view side?

Comment: Yes. See the updated answer. The view should be strongly typed to `PagedList<StudentVm>`

Comment: The error is self explanatory, LINQ cannot convert that C# method to SQL. Why are you calling that ? What is the type of `CreatedOn` ? If it is not `DateTime`, but is `string/varchar` type, you have a fundamental problem to fix. Change that to `DateTime` type

Comment: If `CreatedOn` is `DateTime` type, you do not need to call any extra method. You can directly map. See the update i made to the answer.