# How to implement paging in mvc with sql query

Tags: c#, sql-server, asp.net-mvc

Hi I have one query that is made in sql server as below and the sp name is as 
sp_StudentRequest

```
Select DISTINCT SR.StudentRequestId,SR.RegistrationId,SR.Location,SR.PaymentMethod,SR.CreatedOn,C.ClassName,CC.CampusName,
CASE WHEN ISNULL(TSR.StatusId,0)=0 THEN 1 ELSE TSR.StatusId END AS StatusId,
 substring(
(
    Select ', '+REPLACE(REPLACE(ST1.FromTime,'AM',''),'PM','')+'-'+ST1.ToTime AS [text()]
    From dbo.StudentRequestTimings ST1
    Where ST1.StudentRequestId = SRT.StudentRequestId
    ORDER BY ST1.CreatedOn
    For XML PATH ('')
), 2, 1000) [Time]
FROM StudentRequest SR
Inner JOIN Registration R ON R.RegistrationId=SR.RegistrationId
INNER JOIN Campus CC ON CC.CampusId=R.CampusId
INNER JOIN Class C ON C.ClassId=SR.ClassId 
LEFT JOIN TutorClasses TC ON SR.ClassId=TC.ClassId
LEFT JOIN StudentRequestTimings SRT ON SR.StudentRequestId=SRT.StudentRequestId
LEFT JOIN TutorStudentRequest TSR ON TSR.StudentRequestId=SRT.StudentRequestId AND TutorId=@RegistrationId
where TC.RegistrationId=@RegistrationId
ORDER BY SR.CreatedOn DESC
```

and I am calling this code from controller as

```
public ActionResult TutorDashboard(int? page)
        {               
                    using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(constr))
                    {
                        using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("sp_StudentRequest"))
                        {

                            DataSet GetData = new DataSet();
                            cmd.Connection = con;
                            con.Open();
                            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Operation", "GetTutorRequestDetail");
                            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@RegistrationId", 1);

                            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                            SqlDataAdapter ad = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
                            ad.Fill(GetData);
                            if (GetData.Tables[0].Rows.Count > 0)
                            {
                                ViewBag.TutorRequest = GetData.Tables[0].ToPagedList(page ?? 1, 1);
                            }  
                            con.Close();
                        }
                    }
            return View(ViewBag.TutorRequest);
        }
```

Now I need tom implement the paging in MVC with the help of PagedList, How Can I do so?

If I am not able to make use of this sql query then what is the way to convert this query in entity framework?

Any help will be useful to me.

Comment: You need to project your data in to a model, not a `DataSet`

Comment: @StephenMuecke to get data in model I need to implement entity/linq query right? or we can directly get data from sql query and can fill in model?

Comment: You could use a `DataReader` to read the results. But like using a `DataSet` that defeats the whole purpose of server side paging since you downloading all the data. Using EF with linq is the best approach (.ToPagedList()` uses `.Skip()` and `.Take()` internally to generate the sql query that returns only the records your need)

Comment: But if you do want you use your sp, then add additional parameters for `OFFSET` and `NEXT` (refer [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13220743/implement-paging-skip-take-functionality-with-this-query) for an example (and then use a `DataReader` to project the result into a model)

Comment: @StephenMuecke can you help me out for making this sql query as linq/entity query?

Comment: Not at the moment, but I will take a look in an a hour or 2

Comment: @StephenMuecke ok thanks, I will wait

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/158405/discussion-between-stephen-muecke-and-xtremcool).

Comment: It's same sp as written in this question 
I was trying to transfer this query in entity
I am stuck for comma separated value

Comment: @Stephen Muecke can u help me out to simplify this query in linq.
I have tried that in that another question but stucked for how to get comma separated value

Comment: Also updated that question .
As I had edited from my mobile the layout of sp may not look proper

Comment: Please stick to chat :). I'll take a look in an hour or so (and edit it for you as well)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To apply paging I had converted my query in entity frame work and below is the code

```
var query = (from sr in db.StudentRequests
             join r in db.Registrations on sr.RegistrationId equals r.RegistrationId
             join cc in db.Campus on r.CampusId equals cc.CampusId
             join c in db.Classes on sr.ClassId equals c.ClassId
             from tc in db.TutorClasses.Where(t => t.ClassId == sr.ClassId).DefaultIfEmpty()
             from srt in db.StudentRequestTimings.Where(s => s.StudentRequestId == sr.StudentRequestId).DefaultIfEmpty()
             from tsr in db.TutorStudentRequests.Where(t => t.StudentRequestId == srt.StudentRequestId && t.TutorId == registrationid).DefaultIfEmpty()
             where tc.RegistrationId == registrationid
             select new
             {
               StudentRequestId = sr.StudentRequestId,
               RegistrationId = sr.RegistrationId,
               Location = sr.Location,
               PaymentMethod = sr.PaymentMethod,
               CreatedOn = sr.CreatedOn,
               ClassName = c.ClassName,
               CampusName = cc.CampusName,
               StatusId = tsr.StatusId == null ? 1 : tsr.StatusId,
               Time = db.StudentRequestTimings.Where(p => p.StudentRequestId == sr.StudentRequestId).Select(p => p.FromTime.ToString().Replace("AM", "").Replace("PM", "") + "-" + p.ToTime)
               }).ToList().GroupBy(p => new { p.StudentRequestId }).Select(g => g.First()).ToList();


          var model = query.AsEnumerable().Select(x => new TutorDashboard
           {
              StudentRequestId = x.StudentRequestId,
              RegistrationId = x.RegistrationId,
              Location = x.Location,
              PaymentMethod = x.PaymentMethod,
              CreatedOn = x.CreatedOn,
              ClassName = x.ClassName,
              CampusName = x.CampusName,
              StatusId = x.StatusId == null ? 1 : x.StatusId,
              Time = string.Join(",", x.Time),
               }).ToList().ToPagedList(page ?? 1, 1);
```

And at last I had pass this model on view side.